# What does cheap win mean?

Tags: meaning

Recently I finished a task of investigating some issues and sent out the report. One of my managers replies:

> Sounds like lots of cheap wins found. ...

What does `cheap win` mean here?

Comment: Please provide more context.

Comment: Perhaps positive benefits without much cost or effort

Comment: @Henry seems you are right. This task is expecting at least one week, and I finished it in 1 day...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "cheap win" can have two somewhat opposing meanings:

1. A goal achieved easily achieved (or benefit gained) with little exertion.
2. A triumph which isn't anything to write home about, as the opposition was really pitiful.

In your case it's the first meaning, the report indicated many ways to easily improve things.

Answer (score 1):

In a sports context, a cheap win is one in which the opposition played more poorly than expected, or committed some mistake that handed the game to the other side. In baseball, that might be when an easy fly ball is dropped with two outs in the last inning, with the winning runners on base.  In this case, the team that would have won lost because an error on a play that is made 999 times out of a thousand.